# How to switch between views using Pan Gesture Recognizer in iOS?

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I have two views and i want to use Pan Gesture in Right direction (like the gesture used in Facebook ios app) to switch to second view. The view should start to change as soon as we start to use Pan gesture.How can i perform this? Does anyone have a sample code which performs this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a git with a sample project by which you can reference for the side-menu effect that is in the Facebook iOS app.

https://github.com/BenHall/ios_facebook_style_navigation

**EDIT:**

Okay, then try something like this:

```
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewSwipedLeft:)];
   [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
```

Then handle the swipe with something like this:

```
-(void) didSwipedLeft: (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) gesture {

  if (gesture.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
      return;
  }

  //do something    
}
```

Comment: No pan gesture used in sample project... i need to switch views using pan gesture..

Comment: I want to perform something like this:
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
 [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
 [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
//[panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
 [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

Comment: - (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    
   
  CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
    
    recognizer.view.center=CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x+translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y+ translation.y);
    
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:recognizer.view];
    
}

Comment: With this code, i am able to drag the current view in any direction and while doing so revealing the view underneath it.
But in this code, the missing elements are pan gesture direction, and to change subview as we pan.

Comment: Well, that's why I posted a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` instead.

Comment: You are right, but that would not give the ability to be able to control the swipe like in facebook app

Comment: did you ever come to a conclusion on this one?